# GDB: newline before prompt

Tags: gdb

This would seem like an obvious question, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere, despite some Googling & digging about (even on this site).

When using GDB, is there a way to add a newline before each new `(gdb)` prompt? The default on the system I'm using is no space, and it gets very difficult to read.

Does GDB take an option file like vim, screen, etc? E.g. `~/.gdbrc`

Answer (score 1):

You can [set new prompt](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Prompt.html) with `set prompt`:

```
$ gdb -q
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) set prompt \n(gdb) 

(gdb) 

(gdb) show prompt
Gdb's prompt is "\n(gdb) ".

(gdb)
```

To make this change permanent you can add this setting to your `~/.gdbinit` file.